# How to configure MaxDegreeOfParallelism BoundedCapacity MaxMessagesPerTask

Tags: tpl-dataflow

I make a test with [Walkthrough: Using BatchBlock and BatchedJoinBlock to Improve Efficiency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-using-batchblock-and-batchedjoinblock-to-improve-efficiency/), I got confused by `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, `BoundedCapacity`, `MaxMessagesPerTask`, how to use them to improve the performance.
I make a test with code below, increase the `BoundedCapacity`  from `-1` to `30`, I found the time is longest when `BoundedCapacity`  equals '-1', it is shortest when equals '1', then increase from `2`, the timer increase and bigger then equals `1`.
When I make test with `BoundedCapacity`, `MaxMessagesPerTask`, the time seems not change.

```
            var insertEmployee = new ActionBlock<Employee>(e =>
           AdoDbContext.InsertEmployees(new Employee[] { e }, connectionString),new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
                BoundedCapacity = 30
                //MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 6
                //MaxMessagesPerTask = 5
           });
```

Edit1:
I make a test with and without `BatchBlock`, it did not make such difference like the docuemnt output. The time is much close

Comment: You already configured the options. You won't see any difference though if you *don't* have a lot of data. In any case, executing multiple inserts in parallel *won't* improve performance. You still have to execute 1000 inserts for 1000 objects, only now you have 1000 connections blocking each other. ORM's aren't meant to perform bulk operations.  if you want to insert a lot of data into a database use SqlBulkCopy. The class can take a DataTable or IDataReader as input. You can map a collection of objects to an DataReader with [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member)

Comment: Currently, I make a test with `256` records as the document used, do you suggest to make test with `1000`?Set parallel will reduce the inserting time?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should remove all of this code, create a SqlBulkCopy and feed it your data. Or add the entities to your context and execute a *single* `SaveChanges` at the end.  256 rows is no data at all, it shouldn't have performance issues. Even 1000 is too little. I use SqlBulkCopy inside a *single-instance* ActionBlock to handle thousands of rows per file, for dozens of files. I use a BatchBlock(500) to batch 500/1000 rows at a time and `var reader=ObjectReader.Create(employees); bcp.WriteToServerAsync(reader);` to send each batch to the database

Comment: Thanks. I am learning `Dataflow`, and try to understand the `Dataflow`. I did not have production requirement, just make a test with above link.

Comment: If you *don't* configure BoundedCapacity the input buffer of a block can fill up with messages. Let's say you need to call a REST API with a rate limit, or one that's simply unreliable and can't handle more than 5 concurrent calls. Withoud bounded capacity, the input buffer would fill with messages leading to memory waste. Setting BoundedCapacity ensures that the *source* block will wait before sending more messages if the target block's input buffer is full.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I could understand `BoundedCapacity` is used to control the input source data, and `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is used to control the concurrent tasks. Could you share me when to use MaxMessagesPerTask?